# Poisson process, combined waiting time

Tags: self-study, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Passengers arrive at a railway station according to a homogeneous Poisson process
with rate λ. At the beginning (time 0), there are no passengers at the station.
The train departs at time T. Denote by W be the total waiting time of all passengers
arrived up to the departure of the train. Compute E(W).

My solution:

Let $S_i$ be the arriving time of passenger $i$.

$E(W) = E(E(W|N(T)) = E(E(T\cdot N(T) - \sum_{i=1}^{N(T)} S_i))$

$= T\cdot \lambda T - E(\sum_{i=1}^{N(T)} ES_i)$

$= \lambda T^2 - E(\sum_{i=1}^{N(T)} i/\lambda)$

$ = \lambda T^2 - \frac{1}{\lambda}E(1+ 2+ ... + N(T))$

$ = \lambda T^2 - \frac{1}{2\lambda}E((1+N(T))N(T))$

$ = \lambda T^2 - \frac{1}{2\lambda}(EN(T) + (EN(T))^2)$

$ = \lambda T^2 - \frac{1}{2\lambda}(\lambda T^2 + \lambda T^2+(\lambda T^2)^2)$

$ = \lambda T^2 - T  - \lambda T^2/2$

$ = \lambda T^2/2 - T$.

I know the answer is wrong but cannot find my mistake.

Comment: Do you have the correct answer?

Answer (score 4):

**Use the units calculus and do reality checks to identify the errors.**  These general principles are helpful for anyone doing any statistical calculation, especially those who are authorities and need to get the answers right!

---

First -- responding to a comment -- **the answer looks wrong** because intuitively each person waits $T/2$ time on average, so the answer ought to be $T/2$ times the expected number of waiters ($\lambda T$ by definition), equal to $\lambda T^2/2.$  Furthermore, when $T$ and $\lambda$ are small the answer could be negative: take $T=1$ hour, say, and $\lambda = 1$ person per hour: $\lambda T^2 - T = -1/2$ is nonsensical.

Nevertheless, **the strategy looks good**.  I will therefore not attempt to improve on it, but instead will respond to the literal question by demonstrating one simple method to check one's work: namely, by employing the [units calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantity_calculus).

By **tracking the units of measurement** we can find where errors may have crept in.  Notice that $T,$ $S_i,$ and $W$ are in units of $\text{[time]},$, $N$ is unitless, and $\lambda$ must be in counts per unit time, or $\text{[time]}^{-1}.$ **Let's carry these units explicitly in the calculation for as long as they make sense:**

$$\begin{aligned}
E(W \text{[time]}) &= E\left(E\left(W \text{[time]}\mid N(T)\right)\right) \\
&= E\left(E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N(T)} T\text{[time]}-S_i\text{[time]}\right)\right)\\
&= E\left(E\left(T\text{[time]}\cdot N(T) - \sum_{i=1}^{N(T)} S_i\text{[time]}\right)\right)\\
&= T\text{[time]}\cdot\lambda\text{[time]}^{-1} T\text{[time]} - E\left(E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N(T)} S_i\text{[time]}\right)\right) \\
&= \lambda\text{[time]}^{-1} T^2\text{[time]}^2 - E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N(T)} \frac{i}{{\lambda}\text{[time]}^{-1}}\right)\\
&\ldots\\
&= \lambda T^2\text{[time]} - \frac{1}{2\lambda\text{[time]}^{-1}}E\left(N(T)+N(T)^2\right)\\
&\overset{?}{=}\lambda T^2\text{[time]} - \frac{1}{2\lambda}\text{[time]}\left(\lambda\text{[time]}^{-1}T^2\text{[time]}^2 + \cdots + (\lambda\text{[time]}^{-1}T^2\text{[time]}^2)^2\right)\cdots
\end{aligned}
$$

The units of measure in the last term, when expanded out, are $\text{[time]}\times \text{[time]}^{-1}\times \text{[time]}^2 = \text{[time]}^2$ and $\text{[time]}\times (\text{[time]}^{-1}\times \text{[time]})^2 = \text{[time]}^3,$ neither of which is commensurate with the first term, which is in units of $\text{[time]}$ (as it must be).  *This must be where an error occurred.*  Maybe it's not the only error -- and maybe it's not even the first one -- but at least we have found something to correct.

**Evidently, the expectations aren't what were supposed.**  In fact, because the count $N(T)$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda\text{[time]}^{-1} T\text{[time]} =\lambda T$ (unitless), its expectation and its variance are both unitless and equal to $\lambda T.$  Consequently

$$E(N(T)^2) = \operatorname{Var}(N(T)) + E(N(T))^2 = \lambda T + (\lambda T)^2$$

(all unitless).
Continuing from the penultimate line, just before the mistake, we find

$$\begin{aligned}
E(W\text{[time]}) &= \cdots = \lambda T^2\text{[time]} - \frac{1}{2\lambda}\text{[time]}\left(\lambda T + (\lambda T + (\lambda T)^2)\right)\\
&= \frac{\lambda}{2}T^2\text{[time]} - T\text{[time]}.
\end{aligned}\tag{*}
$$

Although the units are now correct  **the value is still wrong:** it incorrectly subtracts $T.$  (We saw at the outset how that can lead to erroneous answers.  Try $T=1/2$ hour and $\lambda = 1$ per hour, for instance.)  Tracking back up through the questions, we see the subtrahend came from the  $N(T) + (N(T))^2$ expectation.  Where did that enter into the calculations?  *At the point where expectations of the $S_i$ were taken.*  This suggests evaluating the expected sum in a different way.

Now, the sum of the $S_i$ doesn't care about the order in which passengers arrived.  If we forget the order, *all the $S_i$ have the same distribution* and, as we well know, that distribution is uniform between $0$ and $T.$  Thus, the expectation of any waiting time is $T/2\text{[time]}$ and the expectation of their sum (conditional on $N(T)$) must be $N(T)T/2.$  Taking expectations we find

$$E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N(T)} S_i\text{[time]}\right) = \lambda\text{[time]}^{-1}T^2\text{[time]}^2/2,$$

which at least is still in units of time.  Using this in place of the second term of $(*)$ gives

$$E(W\text{[time]}) = \lambda T^2 - \lambda T^2/2 = \lambda T^2/2,$$

a *time* that agrees with the intuitive answer.